# Obtaining a Plane object from a PlaneGeometry in three.js

Tags: three.js, geometry, plane

Just trying some some intersection experiments with three.js. Wanted to see if I could figure out when a cube intersected a PlaneGeometry.  I can get the bbox of the Cube easily enough with

```
var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh);
```

where the mesh is the cube's mesh.  I also have a PlaneBufferGeometry object.  It looks like I might get the intersection info from the intersectsBox() method in the Plane object (or vice versa with the intersectsPlane() method in Box3.  But I can't see easily how to get the Plane object from the PlaneBufferGeometry (or PlaneGeometry).  I can create the Plane from three coplanar points or a point on the plane and the normal, but I don't see offhand how to get those from a given PlaneGeometry.  If/when I constructed the PlaneBufferGeometry I could do it from the inputs to that, but how to obtain the Plane from an arbitrary PlaneGeometry object? Still looking but suggestions are welcome.

Comment: A little more research suggests this is rathole of an approach.  Could be possible, but a better approach is to initialize (or set)  a RayCaster with the moving object's position and normalized vector.  Then call intersectsObjects with the set of objects it might intersect.  If the nearest object is below some threshold distance then they have intersected?

Comment: [THREE.Plane()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Math/Plane) has `.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(normal, point)` method.